# sprintf_s problem

Tags: c++, c

I have a funny problem using this function.
I use it as follow:

```
int nSeq = 1;
char cBuf[8];
int j = sprintf_s(cBuf, sizeof(cBuf), "%08d", nSeq);
```

And every time I get an exception. The exception is buffer to small.
When I changed the second field in the function to sizeof(cBuf) + 1.

Why do I need to add one if I only want to copy 8 bytes and I have an array that contains 8 bytes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your buffer contains 8 places.  Your string contains 8 characters *and* a null character to close it.

Comment: So I need to increae the size of buffer by 1 ?

Comment: Yes.  1 is exactly the size of the null terminator.  In my code I even literally write `char cBuf[8+1]` to emphasize the fact that I need place for this extra character.

Comment: I've used `char[sizeof("00000000")]`.

Answer (score 2):

Your string will require terminating '\0' and 8 bytes of data(00000001) due to %08d.
So you have to size as 9.

Answer (score 1):

All sprintf functions add a null to terminate a string. So in effect your string is 9 characters long. 8 bytes of text and the ending zero

Comment: So I need to increae the size of buffer by 1 ?